# SQL - Calculating age from year of birth

Tags: mysql, sql

Am quite new to SQL, slowly learning my way around, but am very stuck with something i'm trying to do. Have tried browsing around to figure this out, but I just can't make sense of it.

Basically I need to calculate the age from the year of birth, then multiply it by seven to get the 'human age'.

So I have two columns I need to retrieve data from, called Dog_id, and Name, which is coming from a table called 'Dogs'. In that dog table, there is a died column, which lists the YEAR that the dog has died. A few years as an example of when the dogs have died, are 2005, and 2008. The data displayed has to be in a column called 'Human age'

So far, I have:
Select dog_id, name
FROM dogs
WHERE DIED > '0'

What can I add to what I have above, to set the current year, obtain the age from when it died, and have that multiplied by 7 to get the dogs human age?

Any help would be very greatly appreciated as I'm very stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have birth date/year in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_SUB(NOW(), birth_year YEARS)` or `DATE_ADD(NOW(), -birth_year YEARS)` to get the age and then directly multiply by 7:

```
SELECT dog_id, name DATE_SUB(NOW(), birth_year YEARS)*7 AS Human_Age 
FROM dogs 
WHERE died > 0;
```

Another option is

```
SELECT dog_id, name DATE_SUB(NOW(), (YEAR(NOW()) - birth_year)*7 AS Human_Age
FROM dogs 
WHERE died > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure it out using this :( This question is so confusing for me :(

Comment: Ive tried this as stated:

Select dog_id, name, (YEAR(NOW()) - birth_year)*7 AS Human_Age from Dogs

But for some reason, it brings the result back as say 61, when I have the answer here, and it's meant to be 24 :/

Comment: It is YEAR (NOW ()) - birth_year and not YEAR (NOW () - birth_year). Double check the parentesis.

Comment: Hmm, when I enter it as you said, I get the error 1064. When i enter it as above, I get results, but not the right ones. Why does this question have to be so difficult lol.

Comment: Sorry I misread because of opening it on my mobile. SELECT dog_id, name, (YEAR(NOW()) - birth_year)*7 AS Human_Age from Dogs WHERE died > 0 should give you the correct result. You probably forgot to add the where condition. Could you please try this? I edited my answer to include this, btw

Answer (score 0):

SELECT dog_id, name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DIED ,NOW()) AS HUMAN_AGE FROM dogs;

You can use TIMESTAMPDIFF, Its arguments are the unit in which you want the result expressed, and the two date for which to take the difference.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate the reply, I really do.

I'm just a bit confused still, sorry.

When I type:

Comment: Sorry you can multiply the difference with 7 to get Human age. SELECT dog_id, name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DIED ,NOW())*7 AS HUMAN_AGE FROM dogs;

Comment: Hmm i must be doing something wrong, Sorry if i'm being a pain, i'm just so confused.

I know I shouldn't hunt for the answer to a question on a forum, but I've been stuck on this question for days unfortunately.

Basically the question I have is:
Calculate the age of the dogs that died, and multiply it by 7 to get their human age. List their dog_id, name and "human age".

In the table, there is a column called 'BORN' which only has the year that the dog was Born, e.g, 1990. The died column, only has the year that the dog died, e.g, 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE()) - year) * 7 AS diedYearsAgo, Dog_id, Name
FROM Dogs
```